# How do I resolve an EISDIR error on Windows when running NPM link

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, symlink

I had npm link working as expected on Windows 11, bought a new hard drive, ported my repos across and npm link stopped working.

When I run `npm link` in the dependency, it seemingly works as expected. When I then run `npm link my-dependency` in the consuming application, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path E:\repos\my-dependency
npm ERR! dest E:\repos\my-package\node_modules\my-dependency
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'E:\repos\my-dependency' -> 'E:\repos\my-package\node_modules\my-dependency'
```

It seems that npm is failing to create the symlink correctly.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out (after a lot of digging through SO and a long conversation with ChatGPT!) that the issue was because the new hard disk was formatted with exFAT and exFAT doesn't support sym links.

To resolve the issue, I reformatted the drive as NTFS using the standard drive formatting tool in Windows (back up data, right click drive in explorer, click format, select NTFS file system, click format, watch data disappear into the ether). Reinstalling the repos (I had tried a few times prior to formatting), running npm install and then re-running the npm link steps were then successful.

As a potentially coincidental aside, npm install is now running in a fraction of the time it was on exFAT